# Regex to find single word surrounded by square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stumped on the following regex problem.

I'm trying to find single words surrounded by square brackets without spaces. Like this:

```
[singleWord]
```

I don't want to find phrases, like this

```
[a series of words]
```

At the moment I'm using this regex:

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
```

It's finding words *and* phrases. Can anyone suggest how to modify it so that it only finds words in square brackets without spaces?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `.*?` with `\S*` in your regex. `.` will match any character including spaces, whereas `\S` will match only non-space characters

```
/\[(\S*)\]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

> `I'm trying to find single words surrounded by square brackets without spaces.`

You can use this regex:

```
/\[([^\s\]]*)\]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You current regex allows anything. You only want letters.

```
/\[([a-z])\]/gi
```